# drop a user in aws redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've created a user in redshift for a database, then I granted few *SELECT* permissions in a schema. Now I need to delete but I can't because the system insists that even after revoking all permissions the user can't be dropped because it has still access to some object.

When I create the user:

```
CREATE USER etlglue WITH
  PASSWORD '******';

grant select on all tables in schema tbl to etlglue;
```

Now when I try to drop:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES  ON SCHEMA tbl FROM etlglue;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public FROM etlglue;
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES  ON DATABASE db FROM etlglue;

DROP USER etlglue;
```

I have tried to apply even a CASCADE in the REVOKE command but neither, I went to the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REVOKE.html). But the output:

[image]

Comment: Do they possibly own a User Defined Function or a View?

Comment: Often 'DEFAULT PRIVILEGES' can prevent a user being dropped.  These are privileges applied by default to objects a user creates in a schema.  The ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES command can be used to remove them:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revoking privileges off schema does not automatically revoke the privileges granted on tables in that schema. Try executing

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tbl FROM etlglue.

along with your other REVOKE statements.

Comment: I had to go and revoke permissions  in every object where I granted any access before drop it

Comment: Often 'DEFAULT PRIVILEGES' can prevent a user being dropped.  These are privileges applied by default to objects a user creates in a schema.  The ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES command can be used to remove them:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html

Comment: How can I revoke all default privileges for a user? @VinceHill

Comment: You would need to find them all in the Redshfit system table PG_DEFAULT_ACL, and generate the SQL you need.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_DEFAULT_ACL.html

Comment: @Dametime, use the syntax described here, noting that you need to have your user retain privileges on the schema in order for it to succeed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the following script from aws-labs to find out what objects are owned by the user that you are trying to drop.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminScripts/user_to_be_dropped_objs.sql

After that edit/drop object and proceed.